# Scraping yesterday earnings from yahoo finance

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from datetime import date, timedelta
today = today.date()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=2)

url = f"https://finance.yahoo.com/calendar/earnings?day={yesterday}"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.text, 'html.parser')
```

I get today earnings (Sunday) symbol rather then yesterday (Friday, last weekday)

```
print(soup.find('a', 'Fw(600) C($linkColor)').text)
FRES
```

Answer (score 0):

The site uses Javascript to download the data from server. You can emulate this requests with this example, e.g.:

```py
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:120.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/120.0",
}

url = "https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v1/finance/visualization"

params = {
    "crumb": "EwuCwsPbKM2",
    "lang": "en-US",
    "region": "US",
    "corsDomain": "finance.yahoo.com",
}

query = {
    "entityIdType": "earnings",
    "includeFields": [
        "ticker",
        "companyshortname",
        "eventname",
        "startdatetime",
        "startdatetimetype",
        "epsestimate",
        "epsactual",
        "epssurprisepct",
        "timeZoneShortName",
        "gmtOffsetMilliSeconds",
    ],
    "offset": 0,
    "query": {
        "operands": [
            {"operands": ["startdatetime", "2023-12-15"], "operator": "gte"},
            {"operands": ["startdatetime", "2023-12-16"], "operator": "lt"},
            {"operands": ["region", "us"], "operator": "eq"},
        ],
        "operator": "and",
    },
    "size": 100,
    "sortField": "companyshortname",
    "sortType": "ASC",
}

# this changes in time ?
cookie = "d=AQABBK8KXmQCEA8-VE0dBLqG5QEpQ7OglmEFEgABCAHCeWWpZfNtb2UB9qMAAAcIqgpeZJj7vK8&S=AQAAAqhyTAOrxcxONc4ktfzCOkg"

with requests.session() as s:
    s.headers.update(headers)
    s.cookies["A3"] = cookie

    data = s.post(url, params=params, json=query).json()
    for r in data["finance"]["result"][0]["documents"][0]["rows"]:
        print(f"{r[1]:<40} {r[2] or '':<40} {r[3]:<30}")
```

Prints:

```
Lewis and Clark Bank                     Q3 2023  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T13:10:00.000Z      
Alzamend Neuro, Inc.                                                              2023-12-15T16:32:00.000Z      
ATIF Holdings Ltd                        Q1 2024  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T21:00:00.000Z      
Barnwell Industries Inc                  Q4 2023  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T23:05:13.000Z      
Quanex Building Products Corp            Q4 2023  Earnings Call                   2023-12-15T16:00:00.000Z      
PharmaCyte Biotech, Inc.                                                          2023-12-15T17:27:00.000Z      
Edesa Biotech, Inc.                                                               2023-12-15T16:10:00.000Z      
Butler National Corporation                                                       2023-12-15T09:47:00.000Z      
Enzo Biochem, Inc.                                                                2023-12-15T16:17:00.000Z      
Everything Blockchain Inc                Q3 2024  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T21:05:00.000Z      
Temas Resources Corp                     Q3 2023  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T20:11:00.000Z      
Vizsla Copper Corp                       Q2 2023  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T21:00:00.000Z      
CANEX Metals Inc                         Q4 2023  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T21:00:00.000Z      
Enwave Corp                              Q4 2023  Earnings Call                   2023-12-15T15:00:00.000Z      
Cannabix Technologies Inc                Q2 2024  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T21:00:00.000Z      
Red Cat Holdings, Inc.                                                            2023-12-15T16:05:00.000Z      
Mission Mining Co                        Futuris Company Earnings Release         2023-12-15T10:59:00.000Z      
Cognetivity Neurosciences Ltd            Q4 2023  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T21:00:00.000Z      
COMSovereign Holding Corp                Q1 2023  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T21:00:00.000Z      
Lennar Corp                              Q4 2023  Earnings Call                   2023-12-15T16:00:00.000Z      
Liberty Star Uranium & Metals Corp       Q3 2023  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T21:00:00.000Z      
Catheter Precision, Inc.                                                          2023-12-15T17:21:00.000Z      
Scienjoy Holding Corp                    Q3 2023  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T21:30:03.000Z      
Cielo Waste Solutions Corp               Q2 2024  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T23:03:42.000Z      
U.S. Gold Corp.                                                                   2023-12-15T13:31:00.000Z      
Equity Metals Corp                       Q4 2023  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T21:00:00.000Z      
Darden Restaurants, Inc.                                                          2023-12-15T07:00:00.000Z      
DATATRAK International Inc               Q2 2023  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T20:36:47.000Z      
Enghouse Systems Ltd                     Q4 2023  Earnings Call                   2023-12-15T13:45:00.000Z      
MWF Global Inc                           Q3 2023 Kindcard Inc Earnings Release    2023-12-15T21:00:00.000Z      
George Risk Industries Inc               Q2 2024  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T10:59:00.000Z      
TPT Global Tech Inc                      Q3 2023  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T10:59:00.000Z      
High Sierra Technologies Inc             Q3 2023  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T21:00:00.000Z      
Value Line, Inc.                                                                  2023-12-15T12:22:00.000Z      
Mogu Inc                                 Half Year 2024  Earnings Release         2023-12-15T16:00:00.000Z      
Netcapital Inc                           Q2 2024  Earnings Call                   2023-12-15T15:00:00.000Z      
Starcore International Mines Ltd         Q2 2024  Earnings Release                2023-12-15T23:15:10.000Z
```

Comment: How do I get the same results with selenium?